# ¿SE PUEDEN PONER PESTAÑAS EN UN GUIDE DE MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

¿existe una forma de poner pestañas en MatLab 2017? revisé la documentación y no encuentro nada que me ayude a solucionarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te refieres a pestañas como estas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes ir a Tools>Menu Editor

Te aparecerá una ventana como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí puedes agregar menus y submenus como desees, luego, automáticamente, para cada menú agregado, debería aparecer una función como esta:

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function Untitled_5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Untitled_5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Donde podrás agregar el código de funcionalidad del menú.

Comment: Buenos días amigo, ¿esas son las pestañas de navegación? yo me refiero a las pestañas que le colocan a las app así como si fueran pestañas de google, que cada una me muestre la información que contengan.

Comment: Mas que nada funciona como menú, pero podrías darle la funcionalidad que desees, depende del código obviamente.

Comment: También puedes usar **Tools>ToolBar Editor** y usar éstas como pestañas con la funcionalidad que dices, cada botón podría llevarte a un entorno diferente con información diferente, claro, siempre depende del código vinculado a cada botón.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme